# Запятая перед "если"

Tags: пунктуация

Предложение такое: "В Академии учатся в основном аристократы, а в высшем командовании их хорошо(,) если половина". Нужна ли тут запятая перед "если"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Часто задают вопросы о пунктуации в предложениях разговорного стиля. Хочу процитировать Розенталя:
"Различные трудности возникают при пунктуационном оформлении текстов разговорной речи. В некоторых случаях представляется возможным находить какие-то соотношения между конструкциями разговорной речи и конструкциями речи книжной (кодифицированного литературного языка), проводить аналогию между теми и другими; иногда такое сопоставление невозможно и приходится искать особые критерии для решения вопроса о знаках препинания в текстах разговорной речи...**Чаще всего пишущие опираются на интонацию".** 
Я бы запятую не поставила. Во-первых, опираясь на интонацию .Во-вторых, воспринимая *хорошо если половина* как единое целое = не более половины, немного.